# Why some negative functions are negligible but others not

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials, elementary-functions

I am aware that negligible functions that have a negative fixed power are not negligible. However, I am slightly confused and unsure as to why the following two examples are **NOT** negligible functions:

$1)~~~~ f(n) = n^{-\log n} ~$
$2)~~~~ f(n) = n^{-512} $

Similarly, I also do not understand why a negligible function $~f~$, is still negligible when it is $~f(n)^{-1}~$ but then a polynomial function $~t~$ that is $~t(n)^{-1}~$ is not negligible.

Been trying to understand this elementary math but I been breaking my head for too long. Would be amazing if someone could give me an explanation for each one as to why it is NOT negligible, as my understanding of negligible functions were that negative powers are always negligible.

.....

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function):

In mathematics, a **negligible function** is a function $\mu : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$
such that for every positive integer $c$ there exists an integer $N_c$ such that for all $x > N_c$,
$$|\mu (x)|<{\frac  {1}{x^{c}}}.$$

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question, Jalalali.

Comment: This user previously posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341450/establishing-negligible-functions and then deleted it, rather than improve it.

Answer (score 3):

For $f(n) = n^{-512}$ note that for $c = 513$ you never get
$$
|f(n)| < \frac{1}{n^c} \quad\text{that is} \quad\frac{1}{n^{512}} < \frac{1}{n^{513}} .
$$
Thus the clause "for every positive integer $c$" fails, since there is at least one (namely $c=513$) where it is false.

---

Next consider $f(n) = n^{-\log n}$. Note
$$
n^{-\log n} < \frac{1}{n^c}
\tag1$$
if and only if
$$
-\log n < -c
\tag2$$
if and only if
$$
\log n > c
\tag3$$
We know $\log n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, which means: for every $c$, there is $N_c$ so that $(3)$ holds for all $n > N_c$.  We conclude $n^{-\log n}$ is negligible.